# zookeeper watcher in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apache-zookeeper

I am using this gem: `https://github.com/zk-ruby/zk` for connecting to zookeeper, and `get` and `set` commands are working correctly.

I have tried adding a watcher client using the sample zookeeper client that comes along with the server build, and all works well there. I can add a watcher and when I update some znode from another client, the client is notified.

But I wish to integrate a watcher in ruby code, I am not getting any events when data on the node is changed.

This is a sample class:

```
class ZkConnect

  attr_accessor :z, :sub, :k
  include Singleton

  @z = nil
  @sub = nil
  @watcher = nil
  @callback = nil
  @watcher = nil

  def initialize
    initialize_conns
  end

  def initialize_conns
    @z = ZK.new("localhost:2181")
    Rails.logger.info @z.inspect
    # Rails.logger.info z.get_children(:path => "/system/production")
    # Rails.logger.info z.get(:path => "/system/production")[:data]

    # @sub = @z.register("/mypath") do |event, zookeeper_client|
    #   Rails.logger.info "got an event"
    #   Rails.logger.info "got an event on: #{event.inspect} #{zookeeper_client.inspect}"
    # end
    # Rails.logger.info @sub.inspect
    w = watch
    Rails.logger.info "dsmcldsm: #{w.inspect}"
  end

  # def watcher_callback
  #   @callback ||= Proc.new do |event|
  #     Rails.logger.info "dcbskcn : #{event.inspect}"
  #     # Set new watcher
  #     watch
  #     # Rediscover
  #     # discover
  #   end
  #   Rails.logger.info "nckdj cudsnciu sdcn: #{@callback.inspect}"
  #   return @callback
  # end

  def watch
    # return if @z.nil?
    Rails.logger.info "synapse: setting watch at "

    # @watcher = @z.register("/mypath", &watcher_callback)
    @watcher = @z.register("/mypath") do |event|
      Rails.logger.info "dcbskcn : #{event.inspect}"
      puts "dcbskcn : #{event.inspect}"
      watch
    end
    Rails.logger.info "cudsnciu: #{@watcher.inspect}"
    return @watcher

    # Verify that we actually set up the watcher.
    # unless @zk.exists?(@discovery['path'], :watch => true)
    #   log.error "synapse: zookeeper watcher path #{@discovery['path']} does not exist!"
    #   zk_cleanup
    # end
    # log.debug "synapse: set watch at #{@discovery['path']}"
  end
end
```

I took some code from here `https://github.com/airbnb/synapse/blob/master/lib/synapse/service_watcher/zookeeper.rb` for this, but didn't help.

I tried it on a rails project, tried running on `thin` and `passenger`, though I don't see how it would help.

I also don't see eventmachine as a dependency for this gem, so I don't really know how callbacks would be received.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I read changelog and decided to put a `@z.stat("/mypath", :watch => true)` after registering the watcher. And it started working. No idea why.

Comment: https://github.com/zk-ruby/zk/blob/5854b33ac0d584dacba03a63a5db917620d92a00/docs/examples/events_01.rb

This also suggests something similar.

Comment: It has to do w/ the zookeeper client protocol.  in order to receive a watch notification from the server you have to send a command to the server for a path that includes the path to be watched.  I guess it's a common enough use case to get or stat for a math and you want to remain notified if it changes, so set a watch at the same time.  it eliminates at least 1 round trip to the server.